# Kentico Smart Result layout code

Tags: kentico

In V9, i'm looking to adjust the result HTML. Ideally, i want to remove inline CSS, and use classes. I'm currently looking in \CMSModules\SmartSearch\Controls\UI but haven't found it yet. Am i in the right spot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark, are you using the Search Result web part to display the search result? If so, you can change the transformation for that web part to adjust the result HTML. Or you are doing some different.

Comment: yeah, just found that. It's Friday :) Thank!